# Return Packets Not Being Routed On A Linux Router I Built

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I've created a router running Raspbian on a Pi and connected a bunch of clients to it.

It's just a toy project and I only care about routing between the nodes, so I'm not using NAT or anything like that.

The layout looks like this (I'm playing with ECMP hence the two nodes with an address of `10.0.0.4`):

[image: Network Layout]

I've enabled ARP proxying and IP Forwarding on the router

```
pi@raspberrypi-router:~ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp = 1

pi@raspberrypi-router:~ sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

And Reverse Path Filtering is disabled

```
pi@raspberrypi-router:~ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter = 0
```

I've configured some routes on the router

```
pi@raspberrypi-router:~ ip route show
10.0.0.4
    nexthop dev eth0 weight 1
    nexthop dev eth1 weight 1 
10.0.0.50 via 10.0.0.8 dev eth2
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.85
```

Pinging `10.0.0.50` from the router works happily

```
pi@raspberrypi-router:~ ping 10.0.0.50
PING 10.0.0.50 (10.0.0.50) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.50: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.07 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.50: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.04 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.50 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.049/1.064/1.079/0.015 ms
```

As does pinging `10.0.0.4` from the router

```
pi@raspberrypi-router:~ ip roping 10.0.0.4
PING 10.0.0.4 (10.0.0.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.4: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.05 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.4 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.052/1.069/1.087/0.037 ms
```

However pinging `10.0.0.4` from `10.0.0.50` doesn't work. The reply from `10.0.0.4` is never routed back to `10.0.0.50`, I've verified this with TCPDump

On `10.0.0.4`, I see the ICMP echo request arrive and the reply sent

```
21:30:01.078281 IP 10.0.0.50 > 10.0.0.4: ICMP echo request, id 3819, seq 2109, length 64
21:30:01.078388 IP 10.0.0.4 > 10.0.0.50: ICMP echo reply, id 3819, seq 2109, length 64
```

And on the routers `eth0` interface I see the reply makes it that far

```
21:30:47.078732 IP 10.0.0.50 > 10.0.0.4: ICMP echo request, id 3819, seq 2155, length 64
21:30:47.079286 IP 10.0.0.4 > 10.0.0.50: ICMP echo reply, id 3819, seq 2155, length 64
```

But that's where it ends, the reply never makes it back to `10.0.0.50`

I've done some debugging with `ip route` and it seems fine?

```
pi@raspberrypi-router:~ $ sudo ip route get to 10.0.0.50 from 10.0.0.4 iif eth0
10.0.0.50 from 10.0.0.4 dev eth2
    cache  iif eth0
```

Any ideas whats wrong?

Comment: If your netmask is a /24 then server C will think that A and B are both on the local network and won't talk to the router; it'll just do an ARP.  So the router must be arp'ing on eth2 on behalf of servers A and B.  So on C, does `arp -a` show anything useful for 10.0.0.4 ?  You might find it easier to test with separate subnets.  eg `10.0.1.50` for C, so routing will always push to the router.  On a "flat" network, routers don't exist.

Comment: @StephenHarris proxy_arp is enabled: servers think any other IP in the "LAN" have the visible router's mac.I reproduced the setting using 4 ip netns namespaces (serverA,B,C have just a /24 address, router has only /32 addresses and routes):it works, without even disabling rp_filter . "via 10.0.0.8" appears to be not needed (but works with or without). So OP should really write the exact config of every 4 systems for the problem to be reproducible. btw the only non working thing is pinging .50 from one of the two .4 : one of them isn't in the ECMP elected path and the reply goes to the other .4

Comment: @A.B The reason I asked for `arp -a` output was to prove proxy_arp is working.  The OP is mixing routing and arp'ing.  Routes are not relevant if every device is considered local.  The device doing proxy arp is _not_ a router.  That's why I suggested using different subnets.

Comment: btw using /32 addresses is the same as using /24 addresses with the option "noprefixroute". I'm quite sure it's always needed to do either one and adding manually routes to have arp_proxy working correctly

Comment: @StephenHarris ah ok. Anyway OP's informations aren't complete.